# How to extract substring in Hive

Tags: python, sql, dictionary, hive

I am having trouble trying to extract substring in Hive. The table I am working on has a column called referee_dict, showing the rank and corresponding players' IDs. For example, a record could look like this:

```
[('Bronze1', [2738653, 2738652, 2738655]), ('Bronze2', [2738653, 2738652]), ('Bronze3', []), ('Silver1', []), ('Silver2', []), ('Silver3', [])
```

I am trying to find the players who have achieved bronze 2, so I want to extract [2738653, 2738652] from the list. I know it is pretty easy in Python, however, I looked up Hive's documentation but still do not know how to do it in sql/Hive. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can use REGEX_EXTRACT to extract anything from your data. You can search for Bronze2 in that case to extract your tuple.

Comment: Is this array column?

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I figured out a way.. however I don't know if it is the easiest one. Since it is a string, I am going to use regex to capture the substring after "Bronze1' [" and before next "]". The function I am going to use is
regexp_extract(string subject, string pattern, int index). Hope this helps if anyone has similar questions.